# Creating a client server app using c# that allows user to configure the server to which the app can connect

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am a degree student and I am working on my final year project. It's an app that connects to a remote server in order to manage a certain SQL database created on that server.

I have completed all the functionality for this app except for the part where it connects to the database\server. What I want is for the user to be able to specify, in the setting menu of this app, the ip address of the server to which they want to connect. And then login to the database using their login credentials.

I have searched all over but keep seeing videos where the developer connects to the database through Visual Studio but I want the user of my app to have control by specifying the server to which they want to connect since the machine hosting the database may change in future.

Please I need some guidelines on how to go about this. I am using C# and WPF for this project. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Jean Claude.  Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  To get great answers here, please include additional information, such as what you have tried, and how it did not work.  Focus on one specific problem for each question, rather than on your overall project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SqlServer, you can use the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class in System.Data.SqlClient to generate a connection string based on the login credentials and server that your user will input.

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = <Your server address>;
builder.UserID = <ID>;
builder.Password = <Password>;
builder.InitalCatalog= <Inital db to query>;
```

you can then use `var connnection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString)` to create a connection and query the database.

Comment: I would also like to point out that you should also use a `using` block to garbage collect the connection afterwards